# onServicesDiscovered status is 129 and connect unstable for BLE in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I following the page Bluetooth Low Energy for developing in Android 4.3 for Bluetooth Low Energy

I try connect BLE device by following code:

```
public void connect(final String address) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothLeService Connect function.");
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
        }
        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
    }
```

After connect to the BLE device , it will discover the Service by `mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();` like the following code.

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

        public void onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            if(mBluetoothGatt == null){
                Log.e(TAG, "mBluetoothGatt not created!");
                return;
            }

            device = gatt.getDevice();
            address = device.getAddress();
            try {
                switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:

                    Log.i(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTED:");
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED, device, status);
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                    // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.

                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "STATE_DISCONNECTED:");
                    gatt.close();

                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED, device, status);
                    break;

                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "New state not processed: " + newState);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

But the Android will disconnect immediately after connect , and the status of `onServicesDiscovered` also show **`129`** like the following log

```
D/BtGatt.btif(25992): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 2
D/BtGatt.GattService(25992): onConnected() - clientIf=4, connId=4, address=20:73:20:00:6C:B4
D/BluetoothGatt(27228): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=4 device=2
0:73:20:00:6C:B4
I/BluetoothLeService(27228): BluetoothGattCallback-----newState@@@@@@2
I/BluetoothLeService(27228): STATE_CONNECTED:
I/Device_information(27228): BroadcastReceiver---action = ti.android.ble.common.
ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED
D/BluetoothGatt(27228): discoverServices() - device: 20:73:20:00:6C:B4
D/BtGatt.GattService(25992): discoverServices() - address=20:73:20:00:6C:B4, connId=4
D/BtGatt.btif(25992): btif_gattc_search_service
D/BtGatt.btif(25992): btgattc_handle_event: Event 1006
W/qdhwcomposer(  326): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 266 ms
W/bt-l2cap(25992): L2CA_EnableUpdateBleConnParams - unknown BD_ADDR 207320006cb4
E/bt-btm  (25992): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
E/MP-Decision( 2172): Error setting a sleep mode for secondary cores - -38
D/BtGatt.btif(25992): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 6
D/BtGatt.GattService(25992): onSearchCompleted() - connId=4, status=129
D/BluetoothGatt(27228): onSearchComplete() = Device=20:73:20:00:6C:B4 Status=129
I/BluetoothLeService(27228): onServicesDiscovered-----status@@@@@@ = 129
I/BluetoothLeService(27228): onServicesDiscovered-----129@@@@@@ = 129
W/BluetoothLeService(27228): BluetoothLeService Connect function.
D/BluetoothManager(27228): getConnectionState()
D/BluetoothManager(27228): getConnectedDevices
D/BluetoothAdapterService(1109096104)(25992): Get Bonded Devices being called
D/BluetoothAdapterProperties(25992): getBondedDevices: length=1
D/BtGatt.GattService(25992): getDeviceType() - device=20:73:20:00:6C:B4, type=2
W/BluetoothLeService(27228): connect----------mBluetoothGatt = android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@4227a800
D/BluetoothGatt(27228): connect() - device: 20:73:20:00:6C:B4, auto: true
D/BluetoothGatt(27228): registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt(27228): registerApp() - UUID=c560ac73-9ca3-4c2b-a6d4-7c6ec57b7209
D/BtGatt.GattService(25992): registerClient() - UUID=c560ac73-9ca3-4c2b-a6d4-7c6ec57b7209
D/BtGatt.btif(25992): btif_gattc_register_app
D/BtGatt.btif(25992): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 5
D/BtGatt.GattService(25992): onDisconnected() - clientIf=4, connId=4, address=20:73:20:00:6C:B4
D/BluetoothGatt(27228): onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=4 device=20:73:20:00:6C:B4
I/BluetoothLeService(27228): BluetoothGattCallback-----newState@@@@@@0
I/BluetoothLeService(27228): STATE_DISCONNECTED:
```

Why this condition happened ?

It confuse me a few day...Does someone can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BLE on Android is a mess, check this one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58381

Comment: @Michael But it seems didn't has answer to solve this problem , is it ?

Comment: Nothing I would call a solution. It seems that things get worse with multiple connections so limit to one connection per Gatt and try to live with intermittent connections.

Comment: Based on some of those comments, it looks like it may help to turn off (or at least not be using) wifi at the same time, and to introduce some short (maybe a couple of hundred milliseconds?) delays between doing things like connecting, discovering services, writing characteristics etc. 
After a bit of digging, I came across this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bluetooth/bluedroid/+/android-4.3_r1.1/stack/include/gatt_api.h 

Error 129 is a generic one, look for GATT_INTERNAL_ERROR (0x0081). This number hasn't changed all the way up to Lollipop (5.1.1).

HTH someone :)

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, then I restarted bluetooth. After the restart I, got this status error.

The following worked for me. Here's the code in Bluetooth service:

```
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

            if (status != 0) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

        Timer single_timer = new Timer();
        single_timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
            }
        }, 1000);


        Timer second_timer = new Timer();
        second_timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gattServiceIntent = new Intent(context, BluetoothLeService.class);
                bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                mBluetoothLeService.initialize();
                mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
                //maybe you need wait 0.5-1 second to call connect() after called initialize()
            }
        }, 2000);


                Log.e(TAG, "An error code get at onServicesDiscovered= " + status);
            }
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
            }
        }
```

Comment: For those who STILL have "STATUS=129" even after several retries and Thread.sleep(1000) of mBluetoothGatt.DiscoverServices(). Can solve this issue by disconnect and reconnecting. Meaning calling mGatt.disconnect(); and m.Gatt.connect().